# PL/SQL XMLType operation performance

Tags: oracle, plsql, xmltype

I have a PL/SQL function to parse my XML block and return it into a `VARCHAR` variable. 
My XML block is not too complex. Have only 14 tags and don't have any repeating structure.
Inside my function I made this XMLType operation:

```
SELECT    px_Header
                               || 'R5'
                               || RPAD (NVL (A1, ' '), 2)
                               || RPAD (NVL (A2, ' '), 10)
                               || RPAD (NVL (A3, ' '), 3)
                               || RPAD (NVL (A4, ' '), 1)
                               || RPAD (NVL (A5, ' '), 1)
                               || RPAD (NVL (A6, ' '), 10)
                               || RPAD (NVL (A7, ' '), 1)
                               || RPAD (NVL (A8, ' '), 8)
                               || RPAD (NVL (A9, ' '), 1)
                               || RPAD (NVL (A10, ' '), 16)
                               || RPAD (NVL (A11, ' '), 2)
                               || RPAD (NVL (A12, ' '), 8)
                               || RPAD (NVL (A13, ' '), 1)
                               || RPAD (NVL (A14, ' '), 1)
                               || CHR (13)
                               || CHR (10)
                          INTO lv_return
                          FROM XMLTABLE (
                                  '/IN_DATA'
                                  PASSING px_Block
                                  COLUMNS A1          VARCHAR2 (2) PATH 'A1',
                                          A2       VARCHAR2 (10)
                                                                     PATH 'A2',
                                          A3             VARCHAR2 (3) PATH 'A3',
                                          A4             VARCHAR2 (1) PATH 'A4',
                                          A5     VARCHAR2 (1)
                                                                     PATH 'A5',
                                          A6       VARCHAR2 (10)
                                                                     PATH 'A6',
                                          A7         VARCHAR2 (1)
                                                                     PATH 'A7',
                                          A8              VARCHAR2 (8) PATH 'A8',
                                          A9    VARCHAR2 (1)
                                                                     PATH 'A9',
                                         A10             VARCHAR2 (16)
                                                                     PATH 'A10',
                                          A11          VARCHAR2 (2)
                                                                     PATH 'A11',
                                          A12          VARCHAR2 (8)
                                                                     PATH 'A12',
                                          A13   VARCHAR2 (1)
                                                                     PATH 'A13',
                                          A14         VARCHAR2 (1)
                                                                     PATH 'A14');
```

This function takes 0.0945 seconds to perform. Not to so much, I think. But my process need to iterate 100000 times, so I call this function 100000 time.

Is there any faster way to implement this to improve, even if only a few thousandths of a second?

Comment: Looks pretty simple to me.  You say, "function" but this is just a select statement. I'm assuming you have omitted some code?  How is this being called?

Comment: You say you have a function taking x seconds but then you show us only a single select statement. How do you know the select statement is the bottleneck ? I'm afraid you're just guessing.

Comment: When I say that I have one function, is because I have... one function. The code inside that function is this simple select statement. The remaining code of that function is a return lv_return statement. Simply as that. And yes... I've measure the performance of this statement and I want to now if I can change it. Of course I have more and more code in my process but don't I'm only focus in this.

Answer (score 0):

Combine XML and process one large document instead of many little documents.  This at least reduces the amount of context switches between SQL and PL/SQL, and
 probably allows Oracle to take advantage of other efficiencies as well.

Instead of processing one-row-at-a-time:

```
<IN_DATA><A1>1</A1><A2>2</A2></IN_DATA>
```

Process multiple rows:

```
<ALL_DATA>
    <IN_DATA><A1>1</A1><A2>2</A2></IN_DATA>
    <IN_DATA><A1>3</A1><A2>4</A2></IN_DATA>
</ALL_DATA>
```

With code like this:

```
--Process XML.
declare
    v_strings sys.odcivarchar2list;
    px_Block xmltype := xmltype('
        <ALL_DATA>
            <IN_DATA><A1>1</A1><A2>2</A2></IN_DATA>
            <IN_DATA><A1>3</A1><A2>4</A2></IN_DATA>
        </ALL_DATA>');
begin
    --Get strings.
    select A1||' '||A2
    bulk collect into v_strings
    from
    xmltable
    (
        '/ALL_DATA/IN_DATA' passing px_Block columns
        a1 varchar2 (2)  path 'A1',
        a2 varchar2 (10) path 'A2'
    );

    --Display strings for testing.
    for i in 1 .. v_strings.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line(v_strings(i));
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Results:

```
1 2
3 4
```

---

**EDIT**

If the documents cannot be combined, and if the input string is relatively simple and can be trusted, replacing the XML processing with string functions may significantly improve performance.

The example below uses a smaller input string, but changing from XML to string processing shrinks the time from 30 seconds to almost none.

```
--Process XML.
declare
    v_result varchar2(100);
    v_xml xmltype := xmltype('<IN_DATA><A1>1</A1><A2>2</A2></IN_DATA>');
    v_string varchar2(100) := '<IN_DATA><A1>1</A1><A2>2</A2></IN_DATA>';

    function get_string_from_xml(p_xml xmltype) return varchar2 is
        v_string varchar2(100);
    begin
        --Get strings.
        select A1||' '||A2
        into v_string
        from
        xmltable
        (
            '/IN_DATA' passing v_xml columns
            a1 varchar2 (2)  path 'A1',
            a2 varchar2 (10) path 'A2'
        );
        return v_string;
    end get_string_from_xml;

    function get_string_from_string(p_string varchar2) return varchar2 is
        v_string varchar2(100);
    begin
        return
            substr(p_string, instr(p_string, '<A1>') + 4, instr(p_string, '</A1>') - instr(p_string, '<A1>') - 4)
            ||' '||
            substr(p_string, instr(p_string, '<A2>') + 4, instr(p_string, '</A2>') - instr(p_string, '<A2>') - 4);
    end get_string_from_string;

begin
    --27 seconds
/*
    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
        v_result := get_string_from_xml(v_xml);
    end loop;
*/

    --0 seconds
    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
        v_result := get_string_from_string(v_string);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Another way of looking at this is that your original function takes 2.5 hours to process 100,000 XML documents with a single thread.  That sounds quite reasonable.  Some simple parallelism should be able to shrink the time from hours to tens of minutes.

Comment: Thanks Jon. But in my case I don't have this option. This function is called this one time per XML document. Each document only have one row inside this IN_DATA tag.